# How to enable dictation by voice on OS X?

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

I want to be able to say something like, "*Start Dictation*," to turn on OS X's Dictation feature, instead of having to double-click the fn key.

In *System Preferences* -> *Accessibility* -> *Dictation*, there is an option to "*Enable the dictation keyword phrase*." Here is a screenshot of this menu:

[image: Accessibility - Dictation Menu]

I have enabled this option and tried various phrases and the dictation has not been turned on once.

I'm not sure if this is related, but I have installed the "*Enhanced Dictation*" data:

[image: "Enhanced Dictation" prompt]

Within the "*Dictation Commands*" menu, I have all "*System*" commands enabled, including the "*Start Dictation*" command. Screenshot:

[image: "Dictation Commands..." Menu]

Incidentally, the "*Stop Dictation*" command works perfectly.

Has anyone managed to Start Dictation by voice command?

<sup>(2013 rMBP) -- (OS X 10.11.3)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Look at your first screenshot.
[Enable the dictation keyword phrase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91h4q.png)

To activate dictation by voice command, just speak the phrase "Computer Start Dictation"